# Hammer.js swipe left gesture animation in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, hammer.js, ionic5

I'm trying to have a swipe animation when user swipes left in the device.

Here's a gist of the problem

- When I click on about page button in `Home` page, the app smoothly navigates to `About` page.
- When I hit on back icon button in the top bar of `About` page, it gives a back swipe animation.

I've implemented Hammer.js [swipe left gesture](https://hammerjs.github.io/recognizer-swipe/) for going back but it doesn't show any animation as that of back button animation. How could I achieve that?

I created a working example using [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/chilupa/ionic5-infinite-scroll-postion-top) to better explain the problem. Could anyone please help?

[image: about button]

**HTML**

```
<ion-content (swipeleft)="goBack()">
  <h2>About page</h2>
</ion-content>
```

**TS**

```
export class AboutPage implements OnInit {
  constructor(private location: Location) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  goBack() {
    this.location.back();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got this implemented using [Ionic Gestures](https://ionicframework.com/docs/utilities/gestures).

Here's the [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/swipe-page-animation-ionic5-gestures?file=src/app/app.component.ts). Swipe left to right from about page, it will result a smooth animation and takes back to the page from you where came from.

**Swipe Gesture Animation**

```
async ngAfterViewInit() {
    let gesture = await this.gestureCtrl.create({
      el: this.aboutPage.nativeElement,
      gestureName: 'swipe-left',
      gesturePriority: 100,
      threshold: 5,
      passive: false,
      onStart: () => {
        this.renderer.setStyle(
          this.aboutPage.nativeElement,
          'transition',
          'none'
        );
      },
      onMove: (ev) => {
        if (ev.deltaX > 0) {
          this.renderer.setStyle(
            this.aboutPage.nativeElement,
            'transform',
            `translateX(${ev.deltaX}px)`
          );
        }
      },
      onEnd: (ev) => {
        this.renderer.setStyle(
          this.aboutPage.nativeElement,
          'transition',
          '0.4s ease-out'
        );
        if (ev.deltaX > 100) {
          this.renderer.setStyle(
            this.aboutPage.nativeElement,
            'transform',
            'translateX(400px)'
          );
          this.location.back();
        }
        if (ev.deltaX < 100) {
          this.renderer.setStyle(
            this.aboutPage.nativeElement,
            'transform',
            'translateX(0px)'
          );
        }
      },
    });
    gesture.enable(true);
  }
```

**Result of the animation**

[image: swipe-gif]